# TypeError: object() takes no parameters - creating rolling panel timeseries in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a some rolling timeseries panels (rolling 12 months forward each time) in pandas using the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def main():

    dates = pd.date_range('1995-12-31', periods=480, freq='M', name='Date')
    stoks = pd.Index(['s{:04d}'.format(i) for i in range(4000)])
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(480, 4000), dates, stoks)
    print(df.head())
    rdf = roll(df, 12)

def roll(df, w):
    # stack df.values w-times shifted once at each stack
    roll_array = np.dstack([df.values[i:i+w, :] for i in range(len(df.index) - w + 1)]).T
    # roll_array is now a 3-D array and can be read into
    # a pandas panel object
    panel = pd.Panel(roll_array, 
                     items=df.index[w-1:],
                     major_axis=df.columns,
                     minor_axis=pd.Index(range(w), name='roll'))
    # convert to dataframe and pivot + groupby
    # is now ready for any action normally performed
    # on a groupby object
    return panel.to_frame().unstack().T.groupby(level=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print ("Processing daily beta data...\n")

    try:

        main()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        print ("Ctrl+C pressed. Stopping...")
```

I am however getting the following error:

```
    minor_axis=pd.Index(range(w), name='roll'))

TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Where have I gone wrong?

See below for the complete stack trace:

```
runfile('C:/Users/stacey/Documents/Strategies/Crypto/Data/Daily/beta_create_stack.py', wdir='C:/Users/stacey/Documents/Strategies/Crypto/Data/Daily')
Processing daily beta data...

               s0000     s0001     s0002  ...     s3997     s3998     s3999
Date                                      ...                              
1995-12-31  0.572736  0.411435  0.914554  ...  0.389626  0.846049  0.736057
1996-01-31  0.012432  0.995075  0.254918  ...  0.497208  0.689789  0.140903
1996-02-29  0.901161  0.618174  0.153318  ...  0.126790  0.780571  0.494440
1996-03-31  0.932200  0.812955  0.814507  ...  0.511931  0.693407  0.571828
1996-04-30  0.348410  0.653946  0.591804  ...  0.196170  0.257667  0.880753

[5 rows x 4000 columns]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-181-981f6609137d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/stacey/Data/Daily/beta_create_stack.py', wdir='C:/Users/stacey/Documents/Strategies/Crypto/Data/Daily')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/stacey/Data/Daily/beta_create_stack.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/stacey/Data/Daily/beta_create_stack.py", line 17, in main
    rdf = roll(df, 12)

  File "C:/Users/stacey/Data/Daily/beta_create_stack.py", line 29, in roll
    minor_axis=pd.Index(range(w), name='roll'))

TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-181-981f6609137d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/stacey/Data/Daily/beta_create_stack.py', wdir='C:/Users/stacey/Data/Daily')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/stacey/Data/Daily/beta_create_stack.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/stacey/Data/Daily/beta_create_stack.py", line 17, in main
    rdf = roll(df, 12)

  File "C:/Users/stacey/Data/Daily/beta_create_stack.py", line 29, in roll
    minor_axis=pd.Index(range(w), name='roll'))

TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: Please show the whole stack trace.

Comment: Why are you using Panels? It was deprecated in 0.20